# What is the best practice to show and create an enum using UI in JavaFX?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I have a form with a `ComboBox` which I'd like to be populated with available values of `MyEnum` type:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  FIRST_CHOICE ("First choice"),
  SECOND_CHOICE ("Second choice");

  private String value;

  MyEnum(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return value;
  }
}

myComboBox.getItems().setAll(MyEnum.values());
```

Then, after making a choice and hitting a button for example, I'd like to create a new `MyEnum` object. The ideas I came up with are:

**Option 1:**

Get values from the ComboBox and using `switch` statement, create a new `MyEnum` regarding to the choice taken.

**Option 2:**

Make the String values same as the enumerated ones and create `MyEnum` using `valueOf()`:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  FIRST_CHOICE ("FIRST_CHOICE"),
  SECOND_CHOICE ("FIRST_CHOICE");

  ...
}

MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.valueOf(myComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())
```

**---------**

So the first option is terrible, I know. Second is a bit better but no so user-friendly (since he will see a text like "FIRST_CHOICE") and I suppose there are better options. I'd like to make it in the best possible way, with separation of View and Model as much as I can but I totally don't know how can I achieve that.

Comment: `valueOf` does not create a new enum constant. It returns the existing one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with "option 3", and use the a `StringConverter`. This will allow you to use enum "under the hood" whilst displaying a more suitable String to the user. This will also allow different strings in different situations, e.g. internationalization, or different comboboxes on top of same underlying type.

Here I've used a case statement as an example, but could look the value up from properties file etc.

```
ComboBox<MyEnum> myComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
myComboBox.getItems().setAll(MyEnum.values());
myComboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<MyEnum>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(MyEnum object) {
        switch (object) {
        case FIRST_CHOICE:
            return "foo";
        case SECOND_CHOICE:
            return "bar";
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public MyEnum fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

[image: Example]

The value returned by the ComboBox will still be of type MyEnum, this can be demonstrated by

```
myComboBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(myComboBox.getValue());
});
```

Output

```
SECOND_CHOICE
FIRST_CHOICE
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I create an enum using this option, when the choice was made? I still will have to use switch (regarding to the ``fromString()`` method)

Comment: @notmyf4ulty myComboBox.getValue(); will return the enum, String converter only used for UI... I'll update answer to reflect this...

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Just didn't notice ``<MyEnum>``. Great answer, thank you.

Comment: @notmyf4ulty Note the comment about `myComboBox.getValue()` returning the enum is true for your "Option 1" too, but this is cleaner because it decouples the display (in the converter) from the representation of the data (in the enum).